# RoR, Tire and Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

Good day, I have a project with elasticsearch and tire gem. 
I have a facet, that returns me letters.

```
facet "some" do
  terms :letter, :order => 'term', :size => 99999
  facet_filter :term, id: id
end
```

I have a output of search query like

```
{
  "_index": "some",
  "_type": "some",
  "_id": "210",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
  "id": 1,
  "letter": "p"
  }
}
```

And many more other records.
It's working nearly ok, but if letter is 'a', facet doesn't want to return it to me. I think, it pushes it to "missing".

```
"facets": {
  "fac": {
     "_type": "terms",
     "missing": 27,
     "total": 261,
     "other": 0,
     "terms": [
```

Sounds like a magic.
Where can be the problem? And how can I look through missing records? (I'm using Sense extension to work with ES faster)

Comment: Could it be that the `letter` field has a `stop` filter on it which is removing the word `"a"`?

Comment: Or indeed uses an analyzer that includes a stop filter by default (e.g. `standard` or `snowball`)

Comment: so, as I understood, it had a stop filter. I made letter output as "a_letter", "b_letter" etc and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, it had some filter which is removing the letter "a".
I rewrite method, that returns my first letters, so my new output was "a_letter", "b_letter" etc. and it worked for me.
Thanks [@Shadwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120518/shadwell) for help.